# chromium browser 34 version repository download

Tags: 12.04, chromium

Can someone please help me with downloading chromium browser 34 version, any repository or ppa. I want chromium-browser 34 version only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/chromium-browser/ - It contents some chrome fixes! The actual chrome browser is "chromium-browser_34.0.1847.116-0ubuntu~1.13.10.0~pkg991_i386.deb"

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser/

That should be fairly easy to install.

Comment: Need 34 version chromium-browser .deb file..I am trying to make an image using UCK in which i have to install chromium browser from command promt. Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Find the link here & download chromium(34 version) .deb package for `i386`

Visit http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/chromium-browser/download

For `amd64`

Visit http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/chromium-browser/download

Comment: Is there any way that I can install this on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: yep. You download the .deb package & double click, installation would start.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/chromium-browser/download This is updated to version 36 now